# What is the difference between kCFCalendarUnitWeekday and kCFCalendarUnitDay?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFCalendarRef/Reference/reference.html):

> ```
> kCFCalendarUnitDay
> ```
>
> Specifies the day unit.

and

> ```
> kCFCalendarUnitWeekday
> ```
>
> Specifies the weekday unit. The
>   weekday units are the numbers 1-N
>   (where for the Gregorian calendar N=7
>   and 1 is Sunday).

I wanted an alarm to go off from Monday to Friday and I thought that `kCFCalendarUnitWeekday` was what I needed, until I woke up this Saturday :) Can someone explain what is the difference between these two, as the documentation doesn't seem very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kCFCalendarUnitDay` specifies the day of the month, i.e. a number between 1 and 31 in the Gregorian Calendar.

`kCFCalendarUnitWeekday` specifies the day of the week, i.e. a number between 1 (Sunday) and 7 (Saturday) in the Gregorian Calendar.

> until I woke up this Saturday

Can you show us some code?

Comment: Now I see, thank you. My code was looking like  [mondayToFridayNotification setRepeatInterval:kCFCalendarUnitWeekday];, but now I'll try to setup 5 different notifications with kCFCalendarUnitWeek